# Build error after migrating from Crashlytics SDK to Fabric

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Recently, we've upgraded our organization's Crashlytics account to Fabric, and I'm trying to replace the old Crashlytics SDK with the new Fabric SDK in our existing apps. I've followed [the migration instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate), and it's been largely painless, except that I'm now receiving a build error when I try to compile. The line in question that's causing the error is the bootstrap call:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

The error that's being returned is:

```
Error:(55, 11) error: no suitable method found for with(MyActivity,Crashlytics)
method Fabric.with(Fabric) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Fabric.with(Context,Kit...) is not applicable
(argument type Crashlytics does not conform to vararg element type Kit)
```

Evidently, `new Crashlytics()` isn't being recognized as a valid argument for the `with(Context,Kit...)` method for some reason.

Just to rule out something specifically related to the vararg nature of the method call, I also tried it with more than one kit (e.g. `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new MoPub())`) and the exact same error was still returned.

Finally, I tried moving the call to the `onCreate()` method of my Application subclass, and that didn't help either.

---

Relevant sections from build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
  ...
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
  }
}
```

I've also verified that the Fabric plugin is properly installed and working, and that the old Crashlytics plugin is no longer installed:

[image: Plugins list shown Fabric plugin present, and Crashlytics plugin not present]
[image: Fabric plugin running]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out that the old Crashlytics JAR was still hiding in my `libs` folder somehow, and after removing it, this error no longer persists.

I feel a little boneheaded, but I'll leave this up to help any future Googlers who run into the same issue. :)

Comment: I don't have the jar in my lib anymore but I'm still getting your error :(

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For me it was a redundant dependency that the migration tool did not remove after adding the aar. So if you have:
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:+' in your dependencies in addition to the new one, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I found exactly what @TreKing mentioned in his comment.  The upgrade/migration failed to remove the previous dependency from my `app/build.gradle` file.  Look for an old entry like `compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.1.13'` and remove it.