# App couldn't add to fabric crashlytics?

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I have added fabric plugin to my android studio and integrated crashlytics.but the app not registering in fabric crashlytics.studio showing as follows.

[image]

Any one know what went wrong ?

Comment: Try this Answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701943/build-error-after-migrating-from-crashlytics-sdk-to-fabric/28702680#28702680

Comment: Crashlytics needs an active internet connection to register app. When you run your application make sure device is connected with an active internet.