# Red exclamation mark: Facebook SDK and non-existent library

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am using Eclipse and trying to implement a simple Facebook Login to my project, `AndroidFB2`. I added the Facebook SDK library to my project and now it looks like this:

[image]

There is a red exclamation point on the project name. Does anyone know what this means? What type of error is this?

I've been trying to follow tutorials and none of them encountered this red exclamation point.

Steps I took:

1. I downloaded the zip file facebook-android-sdk-master from github
2. I added that library as existing android code to my Package Explorer
3. I created a new Android project `AndroidFB2`
4. In properties, I added the `Facebook SDK` library to it

After completing these steps the red exclamation mark appeared.

**EDIT** : Problems View

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\...\workspace\FacebookSDK\bin\facebooksdk.jar' AndroidFB5      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

Note: I looked at another Stackoverflow post that says to make sure Android SDK 2.3.3 is available. I checked the Facebook SDK folder and it is using  Android SDK 2.3.3. So I believe maybe there is a different error.

Can someone please help?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks

Comment: What does the errors view say?

Comment: Make sure you import it into workspace properly.

Comment: how do I find out what the errors view says?

Comment: Try the [error view](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-error_log_view.htm) and the [problems view](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-31a.htm&cp=0_4_4_1_10)

Comment: I just added the Problems view as you were requesting. Please take a look. It came out a little small so you may need to zoom in a bit. sorry

Comment: Look at this, it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248102/the-container-android-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-facebook-a

Comment: I've been at this for a couple hours now and nothing seems to be working. I still get the same error: The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\workspace\FacebookSDK\bin\facebooksdk.jar' AndroidFB5  Build path Build Path Problem

Comment: Any ideas what that jar file is about?