# eclipse android app error 'Android Dependencies'

Tags: android

I have this error in my first android project 
it sats 
[The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'E:\project workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'  TheSmartHome        Build path  Build Path Problem]

Comment: Is the library on that path?

Comment: does this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025942/how-do-i-add-a-library-android-support-v7-appcompat-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project->Build Automatically and enable it.

Go to: Project > Clean > Clean all projects.

right-click the .jar files (there will be two files select android-support-v4.jar) and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

also try [The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'facebook-android-sdk\facebook\bin\com_facebook_android.jar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248102/the-container-android-dependencies-references-non-existing-library-facebook-a)